# How do I pass data from child view to parent view in MVC2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

Using .Net MVC2, I would like to pass information from a child view to its parent view.  Initially, I thought I could use the `ViewData` collection, but this seems to only work in one direction: from the parent to the child.

Below is a simplified version of what I am attempting in an effort to pass data from the child view back to the parent view.  When running the Visual Studio debugger, I see the ViewData dictionary while stepping through both the parent and child views.  But the statement which should add an item to the dictionary in the child view does not seem to work.  After returning to the parent view, the ViewData dictionary appears the same as before calling the child.

In the parent view:

```html
<div>
    <%
        List<People> ManagerList = ViewData["ManagerList"];
        ViewData["Section"] = "Managers";
        Html.RenderPartial("OrgTable", ManagerList);
        bool didTableRenderAnyRecords = ViewData["TableResult"];
    %>
</div>
...
<div>
    <%
        if (!didTableRenderAnyRecords) {
    %>
    <p>Sorry, no records found</p>
    <%
        }
    %>
</div>
```

In the child view

```html
<table>
    <thead> ... </thead>
    <tbody>
    <%
        bool validRecordDisplayed = false;
        foreach(var manager in Model) {
            if (manager != null) {
               validRecordDisplayed = true;
    %>
    <tr> ... </tr>
    <%
            }
        }
        ViewData["TableResult"] = validRecordDisplayed;
    %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use ViewBag.SomeProperty here. You can also try and use MVC sections (although I am not sure if those are available in MVC2).

Comment: ViewBag does not appear in Visual Studio's 2010 Intellisense with MVC2.  Looks like it was added with MVC3...

Comment: You're right. Why can't you move your parent code to the child?

Comment: For this particular situation, I was able to work around the problem by ensuring that the List<T> passed to the child contains only non-null entries.

However, for future situations, are there ways to pass information from a child view back to its parent in MVC2?

Comment: As for moving the parent code to the child, the example above is greatly simplified from the actual code.  I have five different lists so rather than duplicate nearly identical code I was attempting to use one view for each set of data, and a third child view for each row of the data.

Comment: I think you are not approaching this entirely right. You should have a ViewModel that will have the "ValidRecordDisplayed" populated before it is passed to the view.

Comment: I inherited this section of code from another developer.  It appears that they wanted to display a message if the previous display logic did not find any collection elements that were valid for display.  In this case, validity is a simple null check - I'm sure the check was added when someone encountered null reference errors within the display logic, but that could have been years ago...